# What is that which Alexander Mahone is playing in Prison Break?

Tags: prison-break

In [the first episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhunt_%28Prison_Break%29) of season 2 in Prison Break, When Mahone is asking the other guy to read the case of each escapee, He is playing some kind of crossword puzzle. I think I saw the word quote in the puzzle's title. Would you please shed some light on it?

Comment: Most likely a cryptoquote, which fits the character and all the codes floating around in that show. Probably does it to exercise his brain.

Comment: Are you sure or it's just a guess?

Comment: From the image, that's exactly what it looks like, an encrypted quote that needs to be deciphered. [Cryptograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptogram) are common newspaper puzzles. Now, the *solution* is another thing. ;)